# multipling matrix elements creating a function and using repetition structures

Tags: function, numpy, matrix, structure, repeat

I have the following exercise:

Make a function that takes two parameters, a NumPy matrix and a constant, and uses repetition structures to multiply each element of the matrix and returns the multiplied matrix.

I did it just using repetition structures:

```
np.random.seed(0)
matriz = np.random.randint (1,30, (3,4))
constante = 4

for i in matrix:
    print (i * constante)
```

Can anyone help me to solve it right?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question (which is a terrible exercise, you'll see why in a minute) is trying to help you get used to `for` loops. The array you're working with has two dimensions, so you need to loop over row indices `i` and column indices `j` to access each of the entries in the matrix. You can get the number of rows and columns of the array with the `.shape` attribute, so you don't have to know the shape of the array beforehand.

Here's one solution that modifies the matrix *in-place*, meaning the original matrix gets overwritten.

```py
>>> def scale_matrix(A, c):
...     for i in range(A.shape[0]):       # Loop over row indices.
...         for j in range(A.shape[1]):   # Loop over column indices.
...             A[i,j] = c * A[i,j]       # Multiply the entry and store the result in the same spot.
...     return A
```

**BUT**

This is a futile exercise, because when you multiply a NumPy array by a constant, it multiplies each entry of the array. No need for looping. This way is also faster and much more readable.

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> A = np.array([[1, 2],
...               [3, 4]])
>>> A * 2
array([[2, 4],
       [6, 8]])
```